# fcm onMessage works on simulator but does not work in physical device

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a web developer trying to build a simple hybrid webview app with push notification. So I used `flutter` and `firebase-cloud-messaging`. The `android` side works fine in both emulator and on a physical android phone.

But for ios I have a problem. The `onMessage` callback works in the simulator and generates a `AlertDialog`. But when I test it on a physical iphone, it doesnt work. Nothing pops up. The other callbacks do work(`onLaunch`, `onResume`). Another weird part, is that as soon as the test app is installed on the physical device, the terminal loses connection to the device. So I cannot even see the error logs.

Comment: same here, alert dialog working in simulator

Answer (score -1):

For me, It depends on version of
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'`
on build.gradle